# How does Excel convert Date to Text?

Tags: excel

I have a date 2020-01-30 (yyyy-MM-dd).
When I change the column format to Text it is getting converted to 43860.

I want to know how it is making it to 43860?

I came to know from Microsoft community that its a difference between 01-01-1900 to the written date. Then is should be 43858 . Why its 43860 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel Date/Times are Doubles.  It is the number of days since `1899-12-31`.  If you want to have text instead of a true date you will need to convert it by using the `TEXT()` Function on the worksheet or `Format()` in VBA.

There is an included error so that Excel could be compatible with Lotus 1-2-3.  It assumes that 1900 was a leap year, which it was not.  See: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time

```
=TEXT(A1,"yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: then the days difference is 43858. why its giving 43860 ?

Comment: There was a mess up in the beginning based on some leap year confusion that they just left in.  that is also well documented.

Comment: And remember that `1-1-1900` is `1` not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Cited many times on SO. It's the number of days between Jan-1-1900 (or 1904) and the given date. This is what allows you to do math on dates.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487

Comment: then the days difference is 43858. why its giving 43860 ?